# The most pythonic way of handling exceptions

Tags: python, django, exception

I've got this code:

```
normalize_data['key1'] = json.loads(normalize_data.get('key1', ''))
normalize_data['key2'] = [key for key in
                                json.loads(normalize_data.get('key2', '[]'))]
normalize_data['key3'] = [json.loads(normalize_data.get('key3', ''))]
normalize_data['key4'] = [json.loads(normalize_data.get('key4', ''))]
```

As you can see, every key processes differently.
If any key will be missing, it will raise `JSONEncodeError`. If any value of any key will be in wrong format, it will raise `TypeError`. What is the most pythonic way of handling those?
I tried putting this before the code above:

```
for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']:
    if key not in normalize_data:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Field {key} is missing'})
    try:
        json.loads(normalize_data[key])
    except TypeError:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Wrong format of {key}'})
```

But I don't really like it. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Please clarify what you don't like about it. Also, please fix the indentation.

Comment: @blhsing I don't like, how it looks and the size of the final code

Comment: A sample of your data should allow us to propose a better answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe:

```
for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']:
    try:
        json.loads(normalize_data[key])
    except KeyError:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Field {key} is missing'})
    except TypeError:
        raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Wrong format of {key}'})
```

Answer (score 0):

There will be doubters but I would do it this way:-

```
for key in ['key1', 'key2', 'key3', 'key4']:
  try:
    json.loads(normalize_data[key])
  except TypeError:
    raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Wrong format of {key}'})
  except KeyError:
    raise serializers.ValidationError({'error': f'Field {key} is missing'})
```